# Expectation of sum of last $k$ eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T$

Tags: approximation, matrix-decomposition, random-matrices

Supposing the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T$ are $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\cdots,\sigma_{k+1},\cdots\sigma_{n+k}$($\sigma_1\leqslant\sigma_2\leqslant\cdots\leqslant\sigma_{k+1}\cdots\leqslant\sigma_{n+k}$) and the elements of $\mathbf{A}$ are zero mean and unit variance, is there any way to find $\mathbb{E}(\sigma_{k+1}+\cdots+\sigma_{n+k})$?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that this expectation doesn't depend on the distribution of the elements of $\mathbf A$? Also, you didn't introduce $a_k$, and the body of the question doesn't match the title.

Comment: Your edit hasn't resolved the discrepancy. The title says "last $k$ eigenvalues", the body sums the last $n-k+1$ eigenvalues.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. It's $\sigma$ not $a$. I'm not sure. It might depends on the distribution of the elements of $\mathbf{A}$. Is there a general formula？Some references?

Comment: Your new edit yet again hasn't resolved the discrepancy. In case the title is correct and you're looking for a way to express that correctly: You could change $k+1$ to $n+1$; then it would match the title.